# MapStruct ignore all unmapped properties for specific method

Tags: java, mapstruct

There are several ways to ignore unmapped target properties in mapstruct.

1. We could list all properties to ignore for specific method:

```
@Mapping(target = "propName", ignore = true)
```

2. Or specify to ignore all properties on mapper level :

```
@Mapper(
        unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE
)
```

Is there a way to mix these approaches **and ignore all properties at the method level** without explisently list all of them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the `BeanMapping` annotation you can specify this at method level.

```java
@BeanMapping(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
```

[The javadoc can be found here.](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/api/org/mapstruct/BeanMapping.html#unmappedTargetPolicy())

Comment: It seems like that function is added in version 1.5. Any suggestion for fellow developers who are forced to use older versions?

Comment: Best advice I can give is install the [mapstruct plugin for your IDE (only eclipse or intellij are supported atm)](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/ide-support/) and use the quick-fix option to quickly add ignore mapping annotations.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using version 1.4, you can annotate your mapping method with `@BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)`